# Deriving FileName from data in Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am working on a situation where I want to store my data in pig script into a file. This is pretty straight forward to do that, but I want file name to be derived from the data itself. So, I have a field in data as timestamp. I want to use say MAX(timestamp) as filename to store all the data for that day.

I know the usage of 
STORE data INTO '$outputDir' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage('$outputDir', '2', 'none', ',');

But this variable "outputDir should be passed as the parameter. I want to set this value with a derived value of the field.

Any pointers will be really helpful.

Thanks & Regards,

Atul Aggarwal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MultiStorage you specify a root directory because typically a HDFS installation is shared by many users, so you do not want data written anywhere. Hence you cannot change the root directory but you can specify which field is used to generate directory names within that directory (in your case 2). The [Javadoc](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/MultiStorage.html) is helpful but I am guessing you have seen that already?

Comment: Thanks Mark, I did see it before but I went through it again after you mentioned. As I understand from the API it seems I have to use both the outputdir and have to specify the position in the second argument of Multistorage. The only problem is that it creates another directory under base directory.But I believe that should not be a problem.                           Thanks for your response. Atul Aggarwal